# Adding new multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'i1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                  'i2': ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'],
                  'val': ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3", "lol4", "lol5"]}).set_index(["i1", "i2"])
         val
i1 i2       
A  I    lol1
B  II   lol2
C  III  lol3
D  IV   lol4
E  V    lol5
```

I need to add new index level `i3` from values `[5, 10, 15]`, **using pandas API**, so it looks like:

```
            val
i1 i2  i3      
A  I   5   lol1
       10  lol1
       15  lol1
B  II  5   lol2
       10  lol2
       15  lol2
C  III 5   lol3
       10  lol3
       15  lol3
D  IV  5   lol4
       10  lol4
       15  lol4
E  V   5   lol5
       10  lol5
       15  lol5
```

My tries(ugly):

```
d = np.repeat(d.reset_index().values, 3, 0)

i3 = [5, 10, 15]
r2 = np.tile(i3, 5)

r = np.concatenate([d, r2.reshape(-1, 1)], 1)

d = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=["i1", "i2", "val", "i3"])
d = d.set_index(["i1", "i2", "i3"])
```

Also, I've been looking towards `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, but it's going to make combinations from `i1` and `i2` no matter what I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create list of tuples by values from `MultiIndex`, then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
vals = [5, 10, 15]
tups = [x + (i,) for x in d.index for i in vals]
d = d.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=['i1','i2','i3']))
print (d)
            val
i1 i2  i3      
A  I   5   lol1
       10  lol1
       15  lol1
B  II  5   lol2
       10  lol2
       15  lol2
C  III 5   lol3
       10  lol3
       15  lol3
D  IV  5   lol4
       10  lol4
       15  lol4
E  V   5   lol5
       10  lol5
       15  lol5
```

Comment: Whilst this works, first manually creating all of the tuple combinations seems rather cumbersome.
Shouldn't there be a more efficient approach that doesn't require iterative creation of tuples?

Comment: @MoorzTech - Another idea should be use cross join, but is seems more crazy for me ;)  `d.reset_index().assign(tmp=1).merge(pd.DataFrame({'i3':vals, 'tmp':1}), on='tmp').drop('tmp', 1).set_index(['i1','i2','i3'])`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to reindexing we can also create a new list column and explode.

```
d_new = (d.assign(i3=[[5, 10, 15]] * len(d))
          .explode("i3")
          .set_index("i3", append=True))

print(df_new)

# result:
            val
i1 i2  i3      
A  I   5   lol1
       10  lol1
       15  lol1
B  II  5   lol2
       10  lol2
       15  lol2
C  III 5   lol3
       10  lol3
       15  lol3
D  IV  5   lol4
       10  lol4
       15  lol4
E  V   5   lol5
       10  lol5
       15  lol5
```