# pandas multiindex add new column performance issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                           Band1       lat1       lon1
latitude level longitude                              
41.0     1000  19.50        23.0  41.015335  19.548331
               19.50        44.0  41.015335  19.565497
               19.50        12.0  41.015335  19.582663
               19.75        35.0  41.015335  19.668494
               19.75        83.0  41.015335  19.685660
```

I want to add following column to multiIndex ( this is `DatetimeIndex` Type ):

```
DatetimeIndex(['1979-01-01 00:00:00', '1979-01-01 01:00:00',
               '1979-01-01 02:00:00', '1979-01-01 03:00:00',
               '1979-01-01 04:00:00', '1979-01-01 05:00:00',
               '1979-01-01 06:00:00', '1979-01-01 07:00:00',
               '1979-01-01 08:00:00', '1979-01-01 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2019-12-30 15:00:00', '2019-12-30 16:00:00',
               '2019-12-30 17:00:00', '2019-12-30 18:00:00',
               '2019-12-30 19:00:00', '2019-12-30 20:00:00',
               '2019-12-30 21:00:00', '2019-12-30 22:00:00',
               '2019-12-30 23:00:00', '2019-12-31 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=179305, freq=None)
```

I tried procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236898/adding-new-multiindex-level) but it takes hours of looping without result ( probably due to large number of rows - 179305 in this case.
Desired results would be:

```
                                                    Band1       lat1       lon1
latitude level longitude time                 
41.0     1000  19.50    '1979-01-01 00:00:00'       23.0  41.015335  19.548331
                        '1979-01-01 01:00:00'       23.0  41.015335  19.548331
                        '1979-01-01 02:00:00'       23.0  41.015335  19.548331
                        '1979-01-01 03:00:00'       23.0  41.015335  19.548331
                        '1979-01-01 04:00:00'       23.0  41.015335  19.548331
                        ...                         ...     ...         ...

               19.60    '1979-01-01 00:00:00'       44.0  41.015335  19.565497
                        '1979-01-01 01:00:00'       44.0  41.015335  19.565497
                        '1979-01-01 02:00:00'       44.0  41.015335  19.565497
                        '1979-01-01 03:00:00'       44.0  41.015335  19.565497
                        '1979-01-01 04:00:00'       44.0  41.015335  19.565497
                        ...                         ....
               19.65                                12.0  41.015335  19.582663
               19.75                                35.0  41.015335  19.668494
               19.75                                83.0  41.015335  19.685660
                                                    ...        ...        ...
46.5     850   23.00                                1280.0  46.491333  23.015891
               23.00                                1390.0  46.491333  23.033057
               23.00                                1508.0  46.491333  23.050223
               23.00                                1519.0  46.491333  23.067389
               23.00                                1544.0  46.491333  23.084556
```

Main issue is speed, hence `for` looping is not an option. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `append` option in `set_index`:

```
# toy data
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('aabbcc'), list('111111')], names=['x','y'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(18).reshape(-1,3), 
                  index=idx,
                  columns=list('abc'))

times = [11,22]

# calculate multiplicity of the last index
multi = len(df.index)//len(times)


df = (df.assign(time=np.tile(times, multi))         # replace [0,1,2,3,4] with your datetime series
        .set_index('time', append=True)
     )
```

Output:

```
           a   b   c
x y time            
a 1 11     0   1   2
    22     3   4   5
b 1 11     6   7   8
    22     9  10  11
c 1 11    12  13  14
    22    15  16  17
```

Comment: Looks good, but not exactly what I need. I want to repeat datetime series for each combination of latitude, level and longitude. I have edited desired output for clarification.

Comment: Are all the combination equal in length? In my toy data, they are not, i.e, `2,2,1`